# Parameterized Redshift COPY from S3 via redshift-data API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am issuing a `COPY` command to connect to S3 and load data into Redshift. I am attempting to do so using the Redshift-Data API, which states that it supports parameterized queries. This is what I need. However upon attempting even the simplest example it appears that the Redshift-Data API is in fact *NOT* capable of issuing a `COPY` command with parameters, however it is happy to run other queries through the API. You can reproduce the following in whichever client you use, I tested locally via the cli but I get the same results in the Python boto3 client (which ultimately I would like to use).

Minimal reproducible example

Have a file in S3:

```sh
echo 'id,foo,is_test
1,foo,true
2,bar,true
3,baz,false' > testfile.csv
aws s3 cp ./testfile.csv s3://mybucket/testfile.csv
```

Try to run the copy command via the CLI (or Python, whatever you like)

```sh
###
# DOES NOT WORK
export MYFILE='s3://mybucket/testfile.csv'
aws redshift-data execute-statement \
    --database dev \
    --cluster-id redshift-clister-id \
    --secret-arn 'arn:aws:secret....' \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --sql "COPY public.table FROM :s3_uri IAM_ROLE 'my-iam-role' REGION 'us-east-1' IGNOREHEADER 1 CSV;" \
    --parameters "[{\"name\": \"s3_uri\", \"value\": \"${MYFILE}\"}]"

###
# ALSO DOES NOT WORK
export MYFILE="'s3://mybucket/testfile.csv'"
aws redshift-data execute-statement \
    --database dev \
    --cluster-id redshift-clister-id \
    --secret-arn 'arn:aws:secret....' \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --sql "COPY public.table FROM :s3_uri IAM_ROLE 'my-iam-role' REGION 'us-east-1' IGNOREHEADER 1 CSV;" \
    --parameters "[{\"name\": \"s3_uri\", \"value\": \"${MYFILE}\"}]"

###
# WORKS
export MYFILE="'s3://mybucket/testfile.csv'"
aws redshift-data execute-statement \
    --database dev \
    --cluster-id redshift-clister-id \
    --secret-arn 'arn:aws:secret....' \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --sql "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema.table WHERE column = :s3_uri;" \
    --parameters "[{\"name\": \"s3_uri\", \"value\": \"${MYFILE}\"}]"

###
# ALSO "WORKS" but not for my use case
aws redshift-data execute-statement \
    --database dev \
    --cluster-id redshift-clister-id \
    --secret-arn 'arn:aws:secret....' \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --sql "COPY public.table FROM 's3://mybucket/testfile.csv' IAM_ROLE 'my-iam-role' REGION 'us-east-1' IGNOREHEADER 1 CSV;" \
```

The result from which always gives me something to the effect of:

```
"Error": "ERROR: syntax error at or near \"$1\"\n  Position: ##",
```

Which is always pointing to the position of the start of the S3 URI variable. When I remove the parameters entirely and hard code the value, the `COPY` operation succeeds just fine. I have tried wrapping the parameter in single quotes and also tried the exact same parameter in a `SELECT` query against the API. The `SELECT` query works easily with no hassle, just not the `COPY`.

So ultimately I would like to use the parameters to more safely run the query, because I will not know the `s3_uri` ahead of time. I can certainly go the route of interpolating the string into the query, but at that point I have a SQL injection vector which I do not have control over (the s3 object names). I verified that you can exploit this with a given object name as s3 object names allow whitespace and any character you need in order to create an injection scenario.

I am finding the same strange behavior present in the `redshift_connector` where the parameters work on `SELECT` but not on `COPY`. Any link to documentation or example that states either this is not supported or shows how to do this would be great, I just cannot find it.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. In my case, I'd like to parametrize the column name in a `WHERE :column = :value` query. However, Redshift Data's `execute_statement` substitutes `:column` with a single-quoted value ie. `'column'` which leads me thinking it doesn't really differentiate between SQL identifiers such as table column names and actual SQL values. Hence, I need to sanitise the client-provided column name myself as it could be used as an SQL injection attack vector.

Shame Redshift Data doesn't support parametrising SQL identifiers, only SQL values.

Comment: Agreed! Big shame that it is not suppoerted.

Comment: To avoid [this ugly workaround with stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74209556/possible-to-parametrize-redshift-copy-command), I've instead resorted to concatenating the column name instead of specifying it as a bind parameter **after** validating the column name manually against SQL injections, by verifying it's a valid and existing column name. It's really something that would ideally be done by Redshift Data itself - think I'll raise a new issue on their GitHub.

Answer (score -2):

I suspect you are just missing the single quotes in the passed value.  Try

```
export MYFILE="'s3://mybucket/testfile.csv'"
```

Your shell is stripping the single quotes in your example

Comment: No sir, as I stated in my question I have attempted to do this both with and without single quotes in the s3 uri and have not had success either way. Did you attempt to accomplish this using the CLI and have success?

Comment: Have you tried to run the cli command with "set -x" in your shell?  This could help in understanding what is actually being parsed.

Comment: I have. It is "doing the right thing" with the quotation marks and as I also stated it works if you substitute the `COPY FROM` with a `SELECT FROM` type of query, so the bash script is not the issue. Have you actually tried running this to replicate the issue?

Comment: Are you passing a quoted string parameter into your SELECT type query?  Have you tried your COPY with the s3 object hard coded into the --sql option (no parameters)?  I think you are barking up the wrong tree with selective behavior of Redshift based on statement type being the key.  I could be wrong but what you have shown so far has too many factors changing between the cases to be conclusive.

Comment: I will post all of the permutations of things that have been attempted. It is unclear to me if you actually read the post because all of your comments have already been addressed in the question itself and your "solution" neither works nor solves the problem.