# Possible to parametrize redshift COPY command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

Below is my stored procedure where I am trying to parametrize the COPY command in redshift:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc (accountid varchar(50),rolename varchar(50)) LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$ BEGIN 

/*copy csv data from s3 into the table*/
COPY mydb.my_table
FROM 's3://extracts/raw/data.csv'
credentials
'aws_iam_role=arn:aws-us-gov:iam::<accountid>:role/<rolename>;'
IGNOREHEADER 1 CSV 
FILLRECORD;
commit;
```

However the account id and rolename parameters are not getting passed through the COPY command. Is it possible to do something like this? Any ideas on what I am missing here?

Comment: Can you try to concatenate the IAM role, account ID and role name using `||`?

Comment: well, how will it help? can you provide an example?

Comment: @MP24 concatenate is helpful. Trying with || . Will post answer if my query works

Answer (score 0):

Followed the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70260777/redshift-copy-from-s3-inside-stored-procedure) and it worked correctly

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc (table_name in VARCHAR, s3_path in VARCHAR, iam_role in VARCHAR) LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$ BEGIN 

/*copy csv data from s3 into the table*/
EXECUTE 'COPY '|| table_name ||' FROM '||CHR(39)|| s3_path ||CHR(39)||' IAM_ROLE '||CHR(39)|| iam_role ||CHR(39)||' IGNOREHEADER 1 CSV 
FILLRECORD;';
commit;
```

This worked!!